# How can i only include the whole number and two decimal points in my output

Tags: python, python3

Code is functioning correctly although I need it to be reduced to only two decimal points for example 38374.96 not 38374.967777777

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
amount = float(input("Enter a starting value: "))

result = {}

# looping for 10 times
for i in range(1,11):
    
    # updating amount
    amount = amount * 1.01

    # updating result
    result[str(i) + " years"] = amount

# printing result
print(result)
```

Comment: Wrong forum, not Unix or Linux related. But what you're looking for is probably a format string - do some research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
...
result[str(i) + " years"] = "{:.2f}".format(amount)
...
```

Result:

```
Enter a starting value: 10
{'1 years': '10.10', '2 years': '10.20', '3 years': '10.30', '4 years': '10.41', '5 years': '10.51', '6 years': '10.62', '7 years': '10.72', '8 years': '10.83', '9 years': '10.94', '10 years': '11.05'}
```

Comment: if you're using python3.6 or later, it could even be ```result[f"{i:d} years"] = "{amount:.2f}"```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to support python versions lower than 3.6, you should typically prefer the newer interpolated F-string:

```
>>> x = 1.312345345673845723
>>> f"{x:.2f}"
'1.31'
```